# JavaFX setOnKeyReleased vs textProperty listeners

Tags: javafx, eventhandler

I have a textField named search in JavaFX. I want to run a code when user changes its content. I used the setOnKeyReleased event handler, but it behaves weirdly. Given this code:

```
search.setOnKeyReleased (e -> {
   AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger();
   search.textProperty().addListener ((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
       n.set(n.get() + 1);
       System.out.println(n.get());
   });
});
```

Console prints nothing the first time I release a key inside the search textField;

"1" the second time;

"2
1" the third time,

"3
2
1" the fourth time, and so on.
I cannot figure out why it behaves like this. Can you give an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding new KeyListener on each KeyRelease event. Both listeners and KeyRelease are triggered each time you type anything. Thus, "3 2 1" string is an output from 3 different listeners to `textProperty`.

If you want to track content changes you don't need KeyRelease event at all, just

```
AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger();
search.textProperty().addListener ((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
   n.set(n.get() + 1);
   System.out.println(n.get());
});
```

P.S.: also you don't actually need AtomicInteger here, as listeners are being run on JavaFX UI Thread one by one. So there can't be any concurrents updates (with current code).

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kL2pQ9KABg, but maybe it's wrong (minute 5)

Comment: @Dav, this tutorial author makes the similar error, but his listeners don't have visible effect. They just do the same work over and over again, but because result is similar you don't see the problem.

Comment: The `AtomicInteger` here may be more for modifying a local variable inside a lambda than for the concurrency properties.